# SSH Key Requires A Password Through SSH But Not Through Client

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, ssh-agent

The issue that is occurring is the following;
I was given an ssh key (specifically a `.ppk` file for an AWS server). When I try to use the key through shell, I get prompted for a password; i.e.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/*ssh_key*.ppk *user*@*hostname*
```

However, when I use a client such as `Filezilla`, I am able to simply specify the keyfile during authentication configuration and the client will connect without issues. There is not prompt for authenticating against the keyfile.

This only happens with this one key, I've never had an issue like this before with other ssh keys.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS - kernal 4.15.0.36 #39

Comment: Yes, it appears I lacked the understanding in the difference between keys. I needed to convert it to openssh format and am able to ssh with the converted key.  I didn't realize the issue was with the key format itself. Thank you.